# What's the area of the shape defined by all points whose distances from two focal points multiply to give the same product?

Tags: analytic-geometry, area, plane-curves

This shape, which I call the multiplicoid, is the equivalent of, and very similar to, an ellipse. However, instead of the distance between each point and the two focal points summing to a constant, here the distances multiply to give a constant.

Suppose the two focal points are $(-0.5,0)$ and $(0.5,0)$; and the distance of each point on the multiplicoid to each of these points multiplies to give $1$.

$\sqrt {(x+0.5)^2+y^2} * \sqrt {(x-0.5)^2+y^2}= 1$

Neatly, the $x$ intercepts of this shape will occur at $x= \pm \frac{\sqrt 5}{2}$. The y intercepts occur at $y = \pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$

Could the curve of the multiplicoid be expressed as y = $f(x)$?
What is its area?

Comment: What you have called a "multiplicoid" is classically called a [Cassinian oval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html), after the astronomer. The link I have given has formulae for the area of Cassinian ovals depending on shape. In your particular case, the formula involves the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment to your question, the [Cassinian oval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html) is the name given to the curve that is the locus of a point whose distance from two given foci, when multiplied, gives a constant.

In your particular case, the Cassinian oval you have has the rationalized Cartesian equation $$\left(x^2+y^2+\frac14\right)^2-x^2=1$$

Certainly, you can solve for $y$ here, but the expression is not that convenient I think. As for the area, switching to the polar representation and using the formula for the area of a polar curve, along with taking the fourfold symmetry into account, yields

$$\frac14\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(2\cos 2\theta+\sqrt{62+2\cos4\theta}\right)\mathrm d\theta=2E\left(\frac1{16}\right)\approx 3.0919145$$

where $E(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind, with parameter $m$.